# keep getting error "Unresolved reference: valueOf"

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, kotlin

In in the notes portion of my app i get the error "Unresolved reference: valueOf" in my EquipmentTrackerAllnotes.kt file.

the way my app operates is when you open the app initially it opens up to the dashboard the main home screen, then there is a navigation drawer on the side. One of the fragments in the navigation drawer is my "EquipmentTracker" aka the area where you can make notes of equipment the user may have. In side there you can add notes, delete and edit.

I'm open ears to any recommendations on possible changes i should make as well. But for now my main focus is fixing this error listed above.

EquipmentTracker.kt

```
package com.example.mechanicsapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.mechanicsapp.Model.noteModel
import com.example.mechanicsapp.database.MySqliteHelper
import com.example.mechanicsapp.databinding.FragmentEquipmentTrackerBinding

class EquipmentTracker : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentEquipmentTrackerBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    var intent = Intent(requireContext(), EquipmentTracker::class.java)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in_fragment, container, false)

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentEquipmentTrackerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.root
        val helper = MySqliteHelper(requireContext())
        binding.btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            intent = Intent(activity, FragmentEquipmentTrackerBinding::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

            return@OnClickListener

        })
        binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val model = noteModel()
            model.bumpernumber = binding.bumpernumber.text.toString()
            model.description = binding.description.text.toString()
            model.nsn = binding.nsn.text.toString()
            model.serialnumber = binding.serialnumber.text.toString()
            model.date = binding.date.text.toString()

            if (model.bumpernumber.isEmpty()) {
                binding.bumpernumber.error = "Enter bumper number"
                return@OnClickListener
            }
            if (model.description.isEmpty()) {
                binding.description.error = "Enter description"
                return@OnClickListener
            }
            if (model.nsn.isEmpty()) {
                binding.nsn.error = "Enter nsn"
                return@OnClickListener
            }
            if (model.serialnumber.isEmpty()) {
                binding.serialnumber.error = "Enter serial number"
                return@OnClickListener
            }
            if (model.date.isEmpty()) {
                binding.date.error = "Enter date"
                return@OnClickListener
            }
            val r = helper.saveNote(model)
            if (r) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "note is saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "some thing want wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()

            }
        })
        return binding.root

    }

}
```

EquipmentTrackerAllnotes.kt

```
package com.example.mechanicsapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast

import com.example.mechanicsapp.Model.noteModel
import com.example.mechanicsapp.adapter.NoteAdapter
import com.example.mechanicsapp.database.MySqliteHelper
import com.example.mechanicsapp.databinding.ActivityEquipmentTrackerAllnotesBinding

@Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
class EquipmentTrackerAllnotes : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var adapter: NoteAdapter? = null
    private var binding: ActivityEquipmentTrackerAllnotesBinding? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityEquipmentTrackerAllnotesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding!!.root)
        fetchNotes()
    }

    private fun fetchNotes() {
        val helper = MySqliteHelper(this)
        adapter = NoteAdapter(this, helper.allNotes)
        adapter!!.setOnNoteItemClickListener(object : NoteAdapter.OnNoteItemClickListener {

            override
            fun Onclick(model: noteModel) {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@EquipmentTrackerAllnotes)
                builder.setTitle("Important")
                builder.setMessage("Are your sure?")
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes" ) {

                        dialogInterface, _ ->
                    val helper = MySqliteHelper(this@EquipmentTrackerAllnotes)
                    val check = helper.delNoteById(String.valueOf(model.id))
                    if (check) {
                        fetchNotes()
                        Toast.makeText(this@EquipmentTrackerAllnotes, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@EquipmentTrackerAllnotes,
                            "something went wrong",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                    dialogInterface.dismiss()
                }.setNegativeButton(
                    "No"
                ) { dialogInterface, _ -> dialogInterface.dismiss() }
                builder.create().show()
            }

            override fun OnEdit(model: noteModel) {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@EquipmentTrackerAllnotes)
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(this@EquipmentTrackerAllnotes)
                    .inflate(R.layout.edit_note, null, false)
                val bm = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.bumpernumber)
                val des = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.description)
                val nsn = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nsn)
                val sn = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.serialnumber)
                val date = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.date)
                val btnUpdate = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnUpdate)
                bm.setText(model.bumpernumber)
                des.setText(model.description)
                nsn.setText(model.nsn)
                sn.setText(model.serialnumber)
                date.setText(model.date)
                builder.setView(view)
                val alertDialog = builder.create()
                btnUpdate.setOnClickListener {
                    val model1 = noteModel()
                    model1.id = model.id
                    model1.bumpernumber = bm.text.toString()
                    model1.description = des.text.toString()
                    model1.nsn = nsn.text.toString()
                    model1.serialnumber = sn.text.toString()
                    model1.date = date.text.toString()
                    updateNote(model1)
                    alertDialog.dismiss()
                }
                alertDialog.show()
            }
        })
        this.binding?.recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        this.binding?.recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        this.binding?.recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun updateNote(model: noteModel) {
        val helper = MySqliteHelper(this@EquipmentTrackerAllnotes)
        val check = helper.updateNoteById(model)
        if (check) {
            fetchNotes()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

in my adapter folder I have NoteAdapter.java

NoteAdapter.java

```
package com.example.mechanicsapp.adapter;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.mechanicsapp.Model.noteModel;
import com.example.mechanicsapp.R;
import com.example.mechanicsapp.database.MySqliteHelper;

import java.util.List;

public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.viewHolder> {

    List<noteModel> list;
    Activity activity;
    OnNoteItemClickListener listener;
    public NoteAdapter(Activity activity,List<noteModel> list) {
        this.list=list;
        this.activity=activity;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_note,null,false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        noteModel model=list.get(position);
        holder.bumpernumber.setText(model.getBumpernumber());
        holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
        holder.nsn.setText(model.getNsn());
        holder.serialnumber.setText(model.getSerialnumber());
        holder.date.setText(model.getDate());
        holder.more.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            PopupMenu menu=new PopupMenu(activity,holder.more);
            menu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.more_menu,menu.getMenu());
            menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.edit:
                            listener.OnEdit(model);
                            break;
                        case R.id.delete:
                            listener.Onclick(model);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            menu.show();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
    public static class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView bumpernumber,description,nsn,serialnumber,date;
        ImageView more;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            bumpernumber=itemView.findViewById(R.id.bumpernumber);
            description=itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            nsn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nsn);
            serialnumber=itemView.findViewById(R.id.serialnumber);
            date=itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            more=itemView.findViewById(R.id.more);

        }
    }
    public interface OnNoteItemClickListener{
        void Onclick(noteModel model);
        void OnEdit(noteModel model);
    }
    public void setOnNoteItemClickListener(OnNoteItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }
}
```

in my database folder i have MySqliteHelper.java & TableSchema.java

MySqliteHelper.java

```
package com.example.mechanicsapp.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.example.mechanicsapp.Model.noteModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MySqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="note.db";
    private static final int VERSION=1;
    public MySqliteHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String table1="create table "+TableSchema.note.TABLE_NAME+"("+TableSchema.note.ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+TableSchema.note.BUMPERNUMBER+" TEXT, "+TableSchema.note.DESCRIPTION+" TEXT,"+TableSchema.note.NSN+" TEXT,"+TableSchema.note.SERIALNUMBER+" TEXT, "+TableSchema.note.DATE+" TEXT );";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(table1);
    }

    public boolean saveNote(noteModel model){
        SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TableSchema.note.BUMPERNUMBER,model.getBumpernumber());
        cv.put(TableSchema.note.DESCRIPTION,model.getDescription());
        cv.put(TableSchema.note.NSN,model.getNsn());
        cv.put(TableSchema.note.SERIALNUMBER,model.getSerialnumber());
        cv.put(TableSchema.note.DATE,model.getDate());
        long id= database.insert(TableSchema.note.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        return id != -1;
    }
    public List<noteModel> getAllNotes(){
        SQLiteDatabase database= this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] cols={TableSchema.note.ID,TableSchema.note.BUMPERNUMBER,TableSchema.note.DESCRIPTION,TableSchema.note.NSN,TableSchema.note.SERIALNUMBER,TableSchema.note.DATE};
        Cursor cursor=database.query(TableSchema.note.TABLE_NAME,cols,null,null,null,null,TableSchema.note.ID+" DESC");
        ArrayList<noteModel> list=new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            noteModel model=new noteModel();
            model.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TableSchema.note.ID)));
            model.setBumpernumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TableSchema.note.BUMPERNUMBER)));
            model.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TableSchema.note.DESCRIPTION)));
            model.setNsn(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TableSchema.note.NSN)));
            model.setSerialnumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TableSchema.note.SERIALNUMBER)));
            model.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TableSchema.note.DATE)));
            list.add(model);
        }
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        return list;
    }

    public boolean delNoteById(String id){
        SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
        int d_id=database.delete(TableSchema.note.TABLE_NAME,TableSchema.note.ID+"=?",new String[]{id});
        if (d_id==-1){
            database.close();
            return false;
        }
        database.close();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean updateNoteById(noteModel model){
        SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(TableSchema.note.BUMPERNUMBER,model.getBumpernumber());
        values.put(TableSchema.note.DESCRIPTION,model.getDescription());
        values.put(TableSchema.note.NSN,model.getNsn());
        values.put(TableSchema.note.SERIALNUMBER,model.getSerialnumber());
        values.put(TableSchema.note.DATE,model.getDate());
        int u_id=database.update(TableSchema.note.TABLE_NAME,values,TableSchema.note.ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(model.getId())});
        if (u_id==-1){
            database.close();
            return false;
        }
        database.close();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        if (i<i1){
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TableSchema.note.TABLE_NAME);
        }

    }
}
```

TableSchema.java

```
package com.example.mechanicsapp.database;

public class TableSchema {

    public static class note{

        public static final String TABLE_NAME="tbl_note";
        public static final String ID="id";
        public static final String BUMPERNUMBER="bumpernumber";
        public static final String DESCRIPTION="description";
        public static final String NSN="nsn";
        public static final String SERIALNUMBER="serialnumber";
        public static final String DATE="date";
    }

}
```

in my Model folder i have noteModel.java

//noteModel.java

```
package com.example.mechanicsapp.Model;

public class noteModel {

    private int id;
    private String bumpernumber;
    private String description;
    private String nsn;
    private String serialnumber;
    private String date;

    public noteModel() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBumpernumber() {
        return bumpernumber;
    }

    public void setBumpernumber(String bumpernumber) {
        this.bumpernumber = bumpernumber;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getNsn() {
        return nsn;
    }

    public void setNsn(String nsn) {
        this.nsn = nsn;
    }

    public String getSerialnumber() {
        return serialnumber;
    }

    public void setSerialnumber(String serialnumber) {
        this.serialnumber = serialnumber;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

fragment_equipment_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EquipmentTracker">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bumpernumber"
            android:hint="Bumper Number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:hint="Enter description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nsn"
            android:hint="Enter nsn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/serialnumber"
            android:hint="Enter serial number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:hint="Enter date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
            android:text="Display"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_equipment_tracker_allnotes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EquipmentTrackerAllnotes">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

edit_note.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EquipmentTracker">
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bumpernumber"
            android:hint="Bumper Number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:hint="Enter description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nsn"
            android:hint="Enter nsn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/serialnumber"
            android:hint="Enter serial number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:hint="Enter date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
            android:text="Update"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

//row_note.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        cardElevation="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bumpernumber"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nsn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/serialnumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/more"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_more_vert_24"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

more_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/edit" android:title="edit"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/delete" android:title="Delete"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Is there any more to the error message? Can you post the whole error statement above in your question?

Comment: The `String` in `String.valueOf` refers to the kotlin `String` type, not `java.lang.String`. If you want to convert an `Int` to a `String`, use the `toString()` function (i.e. `model.id.toString()`.

Comment: That is a very large amount of code. Would it be possible to create a [mre] instead?

Comment: @Michael that helped I defiantly appreciate it, i cant be leave i looked over the fact i used  java lang for that instead of kt.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that was the whole error message for it.

Comment: @Michael one more question, after fixing that problem and running the app, when i open the navigation drawer in the app and click on Equipment tracker the app closes and gives me this error code  
```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment EquipmentTracker{720ae0d} (bf51ec29-ddc3-49f3-94b9-616da2504001) not attached to a context.
```

Comment: Well, it's looks like you're initializing the `intent` variable way too early (when the fragment instance is constructed). Do you even need that as an instance variable? Can't it be a local variable inside the button click listener?

Comment: @Michael yeah it could be a local cause it only needs to be accessed when clicked on.